# Regular Expression in PHP to extract all possible combination of phone/mobile numbers using one Regex

Tags: php, regex

i am using php and wants to extract phone/mobile numbers from string, i have string with multiple format of phone numbers like

`$str = '(123) 456-7890 or (123)456-7890 and 1234567890 test "123.456.7890" another test "123 456 7890"';`

i had write one `RE` as,

```
$phoneMatches = '';
$str = '(123) 456-7890 or (123)456-7890 or 1234567890 or "123.456.7890" or "123 456 7890"';
$phonePattern = '/\b[0-9]{3}\s*[-]?\s*[0-9]{3}\s*[-]?\s*[0-9]{4}\b/';
preg_match_all($phonePattern, $str, $phoneMatches);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($phoneMatches);
exit;
```

but it gives me output like this,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1234567890
            [1] => 123 456 7890
        )
)
```

Means only two, but i want all the possible combination of phone numbers and mobile numbers from string of text by using only ONE Regular expression.

Thanks

Comment: Only from *this string of yours*? Or are there any other test cases? Note you forgot to match optional `(` and `)` (and the `.`, I guess)

Comment: i think you can follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew may be other test cases.

Comment: Ok, try [`'/(?:\b|\()[0-9]{3}\)?\s*[.-]?\s*[0-9]{3}\s*[.-]?\s*[0-9]{4}\b/'`](https://ideone.com/XftZDP).

Comment: thanks @Wiktor Stribiżew, It works for me, can it handle other possible combinations?

Comment: can it handle other possible combinations ?

Comment: :) I do not know, you have not provided other scenarios, nor the actual pattern specs.

Comment: ok can you pls modify it to extract phone/mobile numbers with any country code ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late, and I'm not sure if this is what you wanted, but I came up with this solution:

```
[+()\d].*?\d{4}(?!\d)
```

**Demonstration:** [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/myD7UX/3/)

**Explanation:**

- `[+()\d]` - We start by matching anything that might represent the start of a phone number.
- `.*?\d{4}` - Then we match anything (using a lazy quantifier) until we reach four ending digits. *Just a little note:* I considered this as a rule, but it might not always apply. You'd then need to modify the regex to include other cases.
- `(?!\d)` - This is a negative lookahead and it means that we don't want any matches followed by a digit character. I used this to avoid some half-matches.

Another observation is that this regex doesn't *validate* any phone number. You could have anything in between the matches, mainly because of this part: `.*?\d{4}`. This will work depending on what kind of situation you intend to use it.